# MDX - How to select one column and sort the returned data

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, mdx

For a SSRS report, I'm trying to return a list of sorted data from a dimension to use with a parameter.

My dimension is `[Radio].[Radio NO].[Radio NO]` where the last Radio NO is a string.

I can find examples of returning one column while sorting on another but I can't figure out how to sort and return just one column.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the exact structure of your cube / query an avenue you could explore, if you'd like to order alphabetical, is the following

```
ORDER(
   [Radio].[Radio NO].[Radio NO].MEMBERS
  ,[Radio].[Radio NO].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
  ,BDESC
)
```

If you want to order by a measure in your cube, then something like the following:

```
ORDER(
   [Radio].[Radio NO].[Radio NO].MEMBERS
  ,[Measures].[Profit]
  ,BDESC
)
```

This is a possible if you really need to change the column name before hitting SSRS but it has the disadvantage of changing it to a measure:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[thisIsTheNewName] AS
  [Radio].[Radio NO].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
SELECT 
{[Measures].[thisIsTheNewName]} ON COLUMNS,
ORDER(
   [Radio].[Radio NO].[Radio NO].MEMBERS
  ,[Radio].[Radio NO].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
  ,BASC
) On ROWS
FROM [OurCube];
```

Comment: How can I give the returned column an alias or name?  I need to be able to reference it for a report parameter.

Comment: unfortunately no - if you are dealing with a custom set it is not possible to change the column header: should be easy enough to do in SSRS?

Comment: I inherited this report that needs some improvements. I'm new to MDX.  Got decades of SQL experience.  Trying to wrap my head around MDX - totally alien to me. They might allow me to rewrite this in SQL but I'd like to see if I can't get it going in MDX.

Comment: I added an approach for renaming a column but you will need to keep hold of the other column. MDX is a very different language to SQL => ideally you should try to forget sql for a while and just play with mdx if you want to learn it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks whytheq! Based on your answer, here's what I came up with that works:

```
SELECT {} ON COLUMNS,
ORDER(
   [Radio].[Radio NO].[Radio NO].MEMBERS
  ,[Radio].[Radio NO].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION
  ,BASC
) On ROWS
  FROM [OurCube]
```